# opciones de duplican cuando selecciono uno

Tags: javascript

Estoy llenando un select de esta manera:

```
function Pais() {
    console.log("Cargar pais");

    var combo_pais = document.getElementById('id_pais'); //id primer select
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Consulta/getPaises',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (pais) {
            console.log(pais);
            pais.forEach(e => {
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                option.text = e._nombrePais;
                option.value = e._idPais;
                combo_pais.appendChild(option);
            })

        });
}
```

Mi `function` funciona, de primera me aparecen mis unicas 2 opciones, ejemplo

```
option 1
option 2
```

Pero si elijo, cualquiera de esas dos, se vuelve a cargar mi select y me aparece de esta manera

```
option 1
option 2
option 1
option 2
```

Como puedo hacer para que no se repitan?

Comment: Antes del ciclo limpia el contenido del select: `combo_pais.innerHTML = '';`

Answer (score -1):

solo veo que tienen combo_pais.append, pero nunca borras los campos, por lo que siempre que cargue la pagina se te van a agregar mas.

```
function pais() {
    console.log("Cargar pais");

    const comboPais = document.getElementById('idPais'); //id primer select
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Consulta/getPaises',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (pais) {
            console.log(pais);
            comboPais.innerHTML = pais.forEach(e => {
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                option.setAttribute("value", e.idPais);
                option.innerText = e.nombrePais;
                
                return option;
            })

        });
}
```